# Fade and slide effect on navigation (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadein, slide, fadeout

I'm trying to create a "back to top" link that fades in and slides in from left when the user scrolls past a certain point and fades and slides out again after scrolling back up past the same point.

**HTML:**

```
<section id="banner"></section>
<nav id="fixed">
    <ul>
        <li id="top-link"><a href="#">Top</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section id="content"></section>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#top-link").hide();
});

$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= 300) {
            $('#top-link').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#top-link').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

I'm able to get it to fade in and fade out when you scroll past 300px, but as you can see from this example **http://jsfiddle.net/AFMxe/10/** when it fades in and out, the subsequent li items "pop" over to the right. Is there a way to smoothly animate it to slide over at the same time as the fade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about http://jsfiddle.net/AFMxe/11/ ?
Everything I did was adding a few lines of CSS:

```
#top-link {
position: absolute;
margin-left: 50px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

New version here: http://jsfiddle.net/AFMxe/13/

I added the class 'no-top-link' for each of the other list items (could be done better of course) and changed the jQuery fading function to:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= 300) {
            $('#top-link').fadeIn();
            $('.no-top-link').animate({ marginRight: "12px" }, 1000 )
            // 1000 describes the time (in ms) the animation takes, change it as desired
        } else {
            $('#top-link').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT 2:**
That following function should be appropriate

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= 300) {
            $('#top-link').fadeIn();
            $('.no-top-link').animate({'marginRight': '12px'},{duration: 1000, queue: false});
        } else {
            $('#top-link').fadeOut();
            $('.no-top-link').animate({'marginRight': '20px'},{duration: 1000, queue: false});
        }


    });
```

Problem solution: I forgot to add 'queue'.

Explanation:

> queue (default: true)
>   Type: Boolean or String A Boolean indicating
>   whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, the
>   animation will begin immediately. As of jQuery 1.7, the queue option
>   can also accept a string, in which case the animation is added to the
>   queue represented by that string. When a custom queue name is used the
>   animation does not automatically start; you must call
>   .dequeue("queuename") to start it. (Source: http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Finished [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AFMxe/16/)

Comment: This solves the problem of it jumping over, but the navigation isn't centered in its container this way. I'm trying to get the li items that come after the top-link to visually slide over to the right as it fades in.

Comment: @KevinHaag: See my edit. I played around with the pixel values. You have to adjust them to your concrete page design. Is that what you need?

Comment: Really close, but it needs to slide back when you scroll back up past the nav.

Comment: Oh, forgot that!
According to fading in and changing the margin, the function should be 
$(function() {
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(this).scrollTop() >= 300) {
   $('#top-link').fadeIn();
            $('.no-top-link').animate({ 'marginRight': '12px' }, 250 );
  } else {
            $('#top-link').fadeOut();
        }
        if($(this).scrollTop() < 250) {
        $('.no-top-link').animate({ 'marginRight': '20px' }, 250 );
        }
 });
});

Unfortunately there seems to be a bug or something that supresses the second margin animation... I'll take a look at that tomorrow!

Comment: @KevinHaag: Did you see the second edit? That should be the solution.

Comment: That's it! I adapted it a little to get the effect I wanted, but that's perfect! Thanks so much :)

http://jsfiddle.net/AFMxe/26/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `animate` method instead..

```
//FADE IN BACK TO TOP LINK

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#top-link").css('opacity', '0');
});

$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= 300) {
            $('#top-link').animate({
                opacity : 1  
            },400);
        } else {
            $('#top-link').animate({
                opacity : 0  
            },400);
        }
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AFMxe/12/)**

Otherwise you can always use the `visibility` property instead of the `display` property

Comment: The fiddle for this one is a little glitchy — the list items aren't centered in their container and the top-link doesn't always show. I think that's because when the opacity is set to 0, the element is actually still in the DOM, so it's pushing the subsequent list items over. (Correct me if I'm wrong)